# Stop Eclipse from indenting line comments

Tags: php, code-formatting, eclipse-pdt

I want eclipse to not touch my line comments when auto formatting. For example I have an array with values and comments for every field for readability. This to me looks good and readable.

```
$Array ['Person'] = [
    'name',                     //Comment
    'height',                   //Comment
    'a very long field name',   //Comment
    'etc...',                   //Comment
]
```

When auto formatting my Code eclipse moves my line comments like this:

```
$Array ['Person'] = [
    'name', //Comment
    'height', //Comment
    'a very long field name', //Comment
    'etc...', //Comment
]
```

This is not very readable at all to me. I know about the solution with ON/OFF Tags but this doesn't seem very handy and practicle. Also changing the settings within the comments section of the Formatter doesn't change anything about the indentation of the comments.

Any help would be apreciated.